# Javascript wait not working

Tags: javascript

I'm making a Find the Cow clone and I have a working wait function but it's ignoring the code before it somehow.

```
function pausecomp(ms) {
    ms += new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date() < ms){}
}

function newRound() {
    document.getElementById("duck").style.opacity = "1";
    score++;
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
    pausecomp(1000);
    document.getElementById("duck").style.opacity = "0";
    //lots more code that changes where it is...
}
```

The duck stays at opacity 0(more likely is that it's at opacity 1 for a fraction of a second) and the score is added after pausecomp ends.

Comment: Why not just use a `setTimeout`?

Comment: Another approach would be to wrap the code you wish to execute after a certain duration within a `setTimeout` so that code will be executed after your timeout period.

Comment: This is not how concurrency works in JavaScript. It's based on continuations and not blocking calls.

Comment: setTimeout hasn't worked for me which is why I went to alternate timers.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout is what you want.

```
function newRound() {
document.getElementById("duck").style.opacity = "1";
score++;
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("duck").style.opacity = "0"},1000);
//lots more code that changes where it is...
}
```

Comment: The duck moves before it turns invisible again.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling a while function Just call pausecomp after 1000 ms with `setTimeout`.

```
function pausecomp(ms) {
    document.getElementById("duck").style.opacity = "0";
    //lots more code that changes where it is...
}

function newRound() {
    document.getElementById("duck").style.opacity = "1";
    score++;
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
    setTimeout(pausecomp(), 1000);
}
```

Comment: The opacity doesn't change at all with this.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this to not block your JS engine:

```
function newRound() {
    document.getElementById("duck").style.opacity = "1";
    score++;
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("duck").style.opacity = "0";
      //lots more code that changes where it is...
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: The duck moves before it turns invisible again.

Comment: What in God's holy name are you blathering about?

Comment: Exactly what I said. The duck is only supposed to be visible for 1 second before moving. With this the duck moves while it's visible then turns invisible.